# Yii2: зачем в виджетах в методе `init()` вызывать `parent::init()`?

Tags: yii2

В [документации](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-widgets.html#creating-widgets) есть такой пример:

```
namespace app\components;

use yii\base\Widget;
use yii\helpers\Html;

class HelloWidget extends Widget
{
    public $message;

    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();
        if ($this->message === null) {
            $this->message = 'Hello World';
        }
    }

    public function run()
    {
        return Html::encode($this->message);
    }
}
```

С какой целью вызывается родительский метод `init()`, который принадлежит [`yii\base\Object`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-object.html#init()-detail) и сам по себе [ничего не содержит](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/base/Object.php#L115).

Comment: Подозреваю, что в расчёте на совместимость с будущими версиями, где вдруг может начать содержать. Или чтобы не переписывать весь код, если у Вашего объекта сменится родитель.

Answer (score 4):

`init()` является методом любого объекта , который наследуется от `yii\base\Object`.

Когда мы используем `parent::init()` , мы просто вызываем родительский метод.

Для примера у нас есть класс `TestClass`. В данном классе содержится метод `testMethod`

```
class TestClass
{
    public function testMethod()
    {
        //Тут какой-то функционал
    }
}
```

Теперь спустя некоторое время нам пришлось создать новый класс, который должен наследоваться от класса `TestClass`. Назовет его `SecondClass`

```
class SecondClass extends TestClass
{

}
```

В классе `SecondClass` будет по умолчанию присутствовать метод `testMethod`, который содержится в классе `TestClass`. Но нам нужно расширить метод в новом классе. Конечно же мы можем переписать метод и скопировать в новый класс, но это не есть хорошо. Завтра добавят пару новых строк в базовый метод. Тогда как быть?

Поэтому в данном случае мы вызываем родительский метод внутри нового класса.

```
class SecondClass extends TestClass
{
    public function testMethod()
    {
        parent::testMethod();
        //Дополняем код по желанию
    }
}
```

Теперь `SecondClass->testMethod()` всегда будет делать то , что и его родитель.

Такая же ситуация с методом `init()` в Yii. Этот метод используется практически во всех классах, так как наследуются эти классы от `yii\base\Object` и работает он так же, как и метод [__constructor()](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.decon.php) в нативном PHP.

Но есть ещё один момент, связанный с методом `Init()` в Yii.

И вот, что пишет **Qiang Xue** (один из главных разработчиков Yii) по этому поводу:

> С помощью метода Init() можно настроить объект до его полной инициализации. 
>   Например, компонент приложения можно настроить с помощью конфигурации самого приложения. Если переопределить метод Init(), то вы можете быть уверены в том, что конфигурация будет применена. Все это применимо для виджетов и других настраиваемых компонентов.

Ссылка на цитату: [тут](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/3884-init-or-contruct/page__view__findpost__p__21312)

**P.S.** Перевел цитату как мог, но суть будет ясна. Поправьте пожалуйста если что.

Comment: А что подразумевается под полной инициализацией?